# Counting the number of Variables in a function

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, export

I have the following SQL Function that returns an XML using multiple tables. The problem here is that the path is placing all the variables in the `SELECT` as sibling nodes under `CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM` when exporting to XML.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetXML]
(
@Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
RETURNS XML
        AS
BEGIN
RETURN (
    SELECT 
    (
        SELECT
        [Address] = [Property].[Address],
        [Name] = [Person].[Name]
        ...
       FOR XML PATH('CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM'), ROOT('CUSTOM_DATA_ITEMS'), TYPE 
    )
    FROM [Property] LEFT JOIN
         [Person] ON [Person].[ID] = [Property].[ID]
    WHERE   ([Property].[ID] = @Id)
   FOR XML PATH('OTHER'), ROOT('EXTENSION'), TYPE 
);
```

I want the xml returned for each of the variables to look like this:

```
<CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
    <DataItemName>Address</DataItemName> (variable name)
    <DataItemValue>AddressValue</DataItemValue> (value inside table column)
</CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
<CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
    <DataItemName>Name</DataItemName>
    <DataItemValue>NameValue</DataItemValue>
</CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
```

I was thinking of surrounding the variables with a `[cte]` then doing `COUNT([cte].[*])`, but that doesn't seem to work. From there I wanted to have a while loop and stick in the path for each variable.

My current solution is to have something like this but I would have to do this for every variable.

```
SELECT [DataItemName] = CASE WHEN [Property].[Address] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Address' END,
       [DataItemValue] = [Property].[Address]
FOR XML PATH('CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM'), TYPE),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to reduce your question to the necessary, that is great, but I must admit, that I do not fully understand this... And I must admit, that I dislike *Entity-Value-Pairs* and I doubt, that this structure will make you happy...

What I understand is your problem: *... is placing all the variables in the SELECT as sibling nodes under CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM*

**There's an easy trick**: Place an **empty** node between them. This will tell the engine to finish the current element and start a new one.

Here are some suggestions:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE ([Name] VARCHAR(100),[Address] VARCHAR(100),SomeNumber INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('John','John''s street',100) 
,('Steve','Steve''s street',300);

SELECT 'Name' AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/DataItemName]
      ,[Name] AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/DataItemValue]
      ,''
      ,'Address' AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/DataItemName]
      ,[Address] AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/DataItemValue]
      ,''
      ,'SomeNumber' AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/DataItemName]
      ,SomeNumber AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/DataItemValue]
FROM @tbl
FOR XML PATH('DataRow'),ROOT('EXTENSION')
```

The result

```
<EXTENSION>
  <DataRow>
    <CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
      <DataItemName>Name</DataItemName>
      <DataItemValue>John</DataItemValue>
    </CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
    <CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
      <DataItemName>Address</DataItemName>
      <DataItemValue>John's street</DataItemValue>
    </CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
    <CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
      <DataItemName>SomeNumber</DataItemName>
      <DataItemValue>100</DataItemValue>
    </CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
  </DataRow>
  <DataRow>
    <CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
      <DataItemName>Name</DataItemName>
      <DataItemValue>Steve</DataItemValue>
    </CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
    <CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
      <DataItemName>Address</DataItemName>
      <DataItemValue>Steve's street</DataItemValue>
    </CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
    <CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
      <DataItemName>SomeNumber</DataItemName>
      <DataItemValue>300</DataItemValue>
    </CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
  </DataRow>
</EXTENSION>
```

I'd rather put the content as attributes into the element, but this is a matter of taste:

```
SELECT 'Name' AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/@DataItemName]
      ,[Name] AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/@DataItemValue]
      ,''
      ,'Address' AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/@DataItemName]
      ,[Address] AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/@DataItemValue]
      ,''
      ,'SomeNumber' AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/@DataItemName]
      ,SomeNumber AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/@DataItemValue]
FROM @tbl
FOR XML PATH('DataRow'),ROOT('EXTENSION')
```

The result

```
<EXTENSION>
  <DataRow>
    <CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM DataItemName="Name" DataItemValue="John" />
    <CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM DataItemName="Address" DataItemValue="John's street" />
    <CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM DataItemName="SomeNumber" DataItemValue="100" />
  </DataRow>
  <DataRow>
    <CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM DataItemName="Name" DataItemValue="Steve" />
    <CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM DataItemName="Address" DataItemValue="Steve's street" />
    <CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM DataItemName="SomeNumber" DataItemValue="300" />
  </DataRow>
</EXTENSION>
```

But - to be honest - I would not do this at all. I'd put this in a fix structure:

```
SELECT [Name] 
      ,[Address] 
      ,SomeNumber
FROM @tbl
FOR XML PATH('DataRow'),ROOT('EXTENSION')
```

The result

```
<EXTENSION>
  <DataRow>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Address>John's street</Address>
    <SomeNumber>100</SomeNumber>
  </DataRow>
  <DataRow>
    <Name>Steve</Name>
    <Address>Steve's street</Address>
    <SomeNumber>300</SomeNumber>
  </DataRow>
</EXTENSION>
```

Comment: I like your first suggestion. I did not know you could do it that way. However, since I have a lot of tables and names, it gets really cluttered and messy and it gets hard to distinguish what column corresponds with what select. Do you know of a way in which I could have a loop to solve this?

Comment: Hi @DRockClimber, glad that you like it! As you are new here, please allow me one hint: One principle on SO is: *one problem, one question*. Your issue here is: *How can I get elements separated and not all within one parent element?* Your new issue seems to be something like: *How can I get a table as key-value-pair-XML-elements generically?* Please create a (reduced to the minimum!) example with sample data and expected output. New questions draw much more attention and you will get help soon! Place a link here, and I'll pop up there too.